# Overwrite MSI DisplayVersion with Custom String

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a .msi installer (via [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)) for an application I'm working on but the application's version number doesn't fit the X.Y.Z version numbers required my MSI's registry `Version` so the version number is "mangled" into something that does fit and still increases with every release.

I'm okay with this.

`msiexec`, as part of it's final cleanup, converts this X.Y.Z integer-encoded version number into a string and dumps it into the `DisplayVersion` registry entry.  What I'd like to do is *overwrite* that string with my own that contains the actual version number of my application.

This certainly seems possible.  For example...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\19BF4688EE4961F41A44D0282A2340D9\InstallProperties
  DisplayName = (REG_SZ) "Configuration Manager Client"
  LocalPackage = (REG_SZ) "C:\Windows\Installer\41202.msi"
  DisplayVersion = (REG_SZ) "5.00.7958.1000"
  Version = (REG_DWORD) 0x05001f16
```

The `Version` is the encoded value of "5.00.7958", so where did the rest of the `DisplayVersion` string come from?

How, using only wix/msi supported options, do I overwrite `DisplayVersion` in the registry with my own custom string?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a larger change than what you're looking to make, but...

if you set ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 in your MSI it won't register an ARP entry for your product. Then you can create your own ARP entry for your product by populating the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode] keys in the Registry table of your MSI.

Comment: It is indeed not a minor change, but I don't think there is another method. I  use the same approach too.

Comment: I don't believe this will work as setting `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT` to 1 merely results in a `SystemComponent` registry key under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]` set to 1 which tells Windows not to display the product in the add/remove list (indeed removing this key makes it appear).
The `DisplayVersion` still gets written as X.Y.Z and the only way to overwrite it seems to be by writing the key after the installation completes, see for instance [this Chrome ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67348).

Comment: Oh right, you meant ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 will hide the product from the list, and then we can create a different fake product for the list with manually crafted registry keys containing the same information as the hidden product and the display version properly set, I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually accomplished this by having the MSI launch a custom installer binary near the end of the installation procedure.  That program forks a background copy of itself and exits so that the install can finish.

The background task sleeps for a while to let the installation complete and then directly alters the registry to set `DisplayVersion` to the desired string.

There's a race condition here but it hasn't been a problem and updating the string isn't essential.

Comment: **A couple of thoughts on this**: I would avoid hacking the Windows Installer registry keys if at all possible for reasons of reliability. There are always surprises when you tweak something. Moreover, and this is serious, what you suggest here - a sleeping binary poking the registry (even HKLM it seems) - is **distinctively malware-like in its behavior**. This could be flagged by security software of all kinds, and you could be stuck with false-positive complaints if it is a large distribution. A nightmare. I would never do this if your distribution is large. Just my 2 cents from experience.

Comment: Also what happens if the system gets shut down right away after the MSI installation completes?

Comment: It's not without its limitations but it works well.  It's only the `DisplayVersion` which is a convenience, mostly for enterprise customers who like to know what version is on their machines.  Our distribution is large and there have been no problems or complaints.  Still, I'd happily switch to a better, more "official" solution if one can be found.